# Assign to a subset of a column using method chaining in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, method-chaining

I would like to use the modern way of Pandas method chaining to assign values to a subset of a column.

Let's say I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 0, 0, 1]})

   a
0  1
1  0
2  0
3  1
```

I would like to achieve the equivalent of

```
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'a'] = 2
```

with something like

```
df.query('a == 1').assign(a=2)
```

However, the above creates a subset dataframe and does not modify the whole dataframe. Is that somehow possible to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

The `query` method, as its name indicates, is designed for **querying a dataframe**, *not for setting values*.

As such, `loc` is entirely appropriate, noting you can assign to a series via a string:

```
df.loc[df.a == 1, 'a'] = 2
```

More idiomatic may be to use [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html), which you can even use in place:

```
df['a'].mask(df['a'] == 1, 2, inplace=True)
```

You should view "method chaining" as a *means to an end* rather than a requirement or objective in its own right. If you are set on using method chaining, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
df = df.assign(a=df['a'].mask(df['a'] == 1, 2))
```

As an isolated operation, I find this less readable. But you may find it useful with multiple linked operations via method chaining.

Comment: > You should view "method chaining" as a means to an end rather than a requirement or objective in its own right.
Fair enough. Just judging from this talk https://youtu.be/hK6o_TDXXN8 I got the impression that Pandas is promoting method chaining as new default way to do most things. Also be aware that inplace might be deprecated in the future.

Comment: @Jarno, On your first point, IMO style should be left to users. Sure, the Pandas developers can promote a particular approach, but in the end the community (users) gain their own intuition / preference. On your second point, that's a risk with *any* functionality (remember `sort` being renamed to `sort_values`). If the functionality is there and has no deprecation warning, you should be happy to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the value using the following code

```
df[df['a']==1]['a']=2
```